File upload becomes empty after form submit for anonymous users
I've build a form in Drupal 9 with Form API.
When logged in as admin, all is working fine.
Selecting a file as anonymous works, and the validations are checked.
But when I submit the form, the managed_file becomes empty.
Is this a permission issue? Which one?
  /**
   * @param array $form
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state): array {


    $form['logo'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => $this->t('Logo'),
      '#upload_validators' => [
        'file_validate_extensions' => ['png'],
        'file_validate_size' => [2 * 1024 * 1024],
        'custom_validate_image_resolution' => [1500],
      ],
      '#upload_location' => 'public://logos/',
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="col-12">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['submit']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Custom validator for image dimensions where either width or height should
   * meet the minimum size.
   *
   * @param File $file
   *   The file ID to validate.
   * @param int $minimum_dimension
   *   The minimum dimension size.
   *
   * @return array
   *   An array of error messages, empty if no errors.
   */
  function custom_validate_image_resolution(File $file, int $minimum_dimension = 1500): array {
    $errors = [];

    $uri = $file->getFileUri();

    // Load the file as an image.
    $image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($uri);
    if ($image->isValid()) {
      $width = $image->getWidth();
      $height = $image->getHeight();

      // Check if either dimension is below the minimum size.
      if ($width < $minimum_dimension && $height < $minimum_dimension) {
        $errors[] = t('The image dimensions must have at least a width or height of %dimensions pixels.', ['%dimensions' => $minimum_dimension]);
      }
    }
    else {
      $errors[] = t('Unable to load the image file.');
    }

    return $errors;
  }


  /**
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // on choose file, $fids is populated, on submit it becomes empty :/
    $fids = $form_state->getValue('logo');

    if (!empty($fids) && !empty($fids[0])) {
      $fid = reset($fids);  // Get the first element (file ID)

      $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
      if ($file) {
        $errors = $this->custom_validate_image_resolution($file, 1500);

        if (!empty($errors)) {
          // Log errors and set form errors
          foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $form_state->setErrorByName('logo', $error);
          }
          // Delete the file if it's temporary
          if ($file->isTemporary()) {
            $file->delete();
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        \Drupal::logger('my_module')
          ->error('Failed to load file with ID: ' . $fid);
      }
    }
    else {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('logo', t('No valid file uploaded.'));
    }
  }


  /**
   * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $node = Node::create([
      'title' => $form_state->getValue(['title' => 'textfield']),
      'type' => 'my-node',
      'status' => 0,
      'field_logo' => [
        'target_id' => reset($form_state->getValue('logo')),
        'alt' => $form_state->getValue(['title' => 'textfield']),
        'title' => $form_state->getValue(['title' => 'textfield']),
      ],
    ]);
    $node->save();

  }

}


After a successful submit the form starts as fresh form again since you have no '#default_value' set. I don't understand the question.

There is no successful submit. When I submit the form, the submitForm() is not creating the node. Instead it returns the form and shows a message 'logo field is required'. Even when I did add a logo. But that only happens when i'm not logged in. As admin, the uploaded file is correctly added into the node .... I hope you understand what is happening.

Ok. Thanks. The #default_value fixed the problem. Why is there a difference between admin and anonymous user?
